# How to pass form values from a view page to a control page in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to pass the form values to an addPerson function in the following way. A new entry (person) is created in my database however none of the form values are passed. Only a blank entry is created. How do I pass the form values correctly?

```
<form action="<?= site_url("/Admin/addPerson/username/password/accesslevel")?>" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <fieldset>
<legend>Add new user</legend>
  <label for="username">Username:</label> <br>
  <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username"  />
 <br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label> <br>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="" id="password"  />
 <br>
  <label for="accesslevel">Access Level:</label> <br>
  <input type="text" name="accesslevel" value="" id="accesslevel"  />
 <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  />
  </fieldset>  
</form>
```

Controller function:

```
public function addPerson($username, $password, $accesslevel)
{
  // add the person to database with

  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO usersas6 " .
                    "(compid,username,password,accesslevel) VALUES " . 
          "(null,$username, $password, $accesslevel)");

    $this->getAllPerson();

  $this->template->show('Admin', $this->TPL);
}
```

Comment: check in your browser console form action string, `siteurl()` as per CI doc has no leading slash `/`: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#site_url

Comment: both situations, with or without the slash, access the function and create and entry - but form input values are NOT passed

Comment: Please provide some code from your controller to get more help.

Comment: also the whole idea of a form is misunderstood, once you POST it, you'll have all form data available in your controller admin stored in $_POST, you can use formhelper to make things easier and more secure: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: added the controller function

Comment: I tried printing the contents of the variables in the controller function and I got "password" "username" etc. ..which brings up 2 questions: how the get the actual contents of the form input variables instead, and why did the database not create an entry with "password", "username" etc as the entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a strange setup with parameters in the URL to the method at the same time that you are using POST-method.

I suggest that you change `site_url("/Admin/addPerson/username/password/accesslevel")` to `site_url("/Admin/addPerson")` and then only use POST

```
public function addPerson() {
  // GET AND SET POSTED DATA
  $username = $this->input->post('username');
  $password = $this->input->post('password');
  $accesslevel = $this->input->post('accesslevel');

  // ESCAPE STRINGS AND INSERT TO DB
  $sql =  "INSERT INTO usersas6 (compid,username,password,accesslevel) ".
          "VALUES (NULL, ".
          "'".$this->db->escape_str($username)."', ".
          "'".$this->db->escape_str($password)."', ".
          "'".$this->db->escape_str($accesslevel)."')";

  $this->db->query($sql); // EXECUTE QUERY

  $this->getAllPerson();
  $this->template->show('Admin', $this->TPL);
}
```

You should alway validate the input properly so you don't get any xss or sql-injections in the database.